# LINQ Purpose of Include

Tags: linq

In Linq, I have seen the Include keyword used.
What is the purpose of Include?

```
    x=> x.Lists.Include(l => l.Title) 
 .Where(l => l.Title != String.Empty)
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Include` method is used to force EF to eagerly load rows from a child relation.

Your sample code is broken; `Include()` can only be called on navigation properties.